# Laravel Homestead ubuntu 16.04

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, homestead

I have a problem in my homestead machine, when I try to open with my project in chrome (schola.app) I get following error message.

[image: chrome message]
schola.app took too long to respond.
Hers is my /etc/hosts file

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   imad-AO756
192.168.10.10  schola.app
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

my homestead.yaml

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Code
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: schola.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/schola/public

databases:
    - homestead

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

I don't know where the problem exist, I tried to vagrant reload --provision and the problem still exist.

Comment: where does it get stuck? is it during the `vagrant up`? if so, what is the last line you see?

Comment: no in the browser when im accessing schola.app it give me  schola.app took too long to respond.

Comment: Homestead setting seems to be ok. Did you check if it's not an issue with your app

Comment: okey i will try to install new app to verify

Comment: i reinstall the laravel app and the problem still exist :/

Comment: Did you provision the changes on vagrant?

Comment: @AhmedImadTouil Please confirm that you have your project folder inside `~/Code`. Like `~/Code/schola`

Comment: I solved the problem , the problem was i tried to vagrant up from the .homestead folder , i should run the commande from Homestead 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your nginx server in order to serve your application. The following guide will guide you in the process [How To Set Up nginx](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-virtual-hosts-server-blocks-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts--3)  .

In order to configure nginx to serve your laravel application i also recommend you to check out this guide [How to Install Laravel with an Nginx Web Server on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-laravel-with-an-nginx-web-server-on-ubuntu-14-04)

After doing this, your app should have access to your application.